# php - Find and replace two types of matches in a string using preg_replace

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace dashes and the '.php' extension on a string, for example:

Original String:

my-awesome-link.php

Resulting String:

My Awesome Link

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: No need for preg_replace. Just make str_replace(['-', '.php'], [' ', ''], $text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str_replace` to get rid of both '-' and '.php', then `UCWords` to go from 'my awesome link' to 'My Awesome Link'.

Comment: I got this far: $pageName = str_replace( "-", ' ', ucwords($getPageName[1]) );  How to I str_replace the '.php' value also?

Answer (score 0):

The full solution would be this:

```
$pageName = ucwords(str_replace(['-','.php'],[' ',''], $getPageName[1]));
```